# How can i fix dropbear-initramfs filtrated port on boot?

Tags: debian, dropbear

I have installed `dropbear-initramfs` (last version) on my physical server but it works on random. When I restart it, the port I set can be open or filtrated.

I read a lot about it and found out that it could be caused by network interface, it can load sometimes after `dropbear-initramfs`. Any idea how can I fix this?

I tried some scripts to restart the `dropbear-initramfs` but it ended with "can't find network interface". I think its somekind of race condition.